# Flutter Displaying a gridview inside a listview

Tags: listview, flutter, scrollable, flutter-layout

i'm trying to display a search bar above a gridview (from a stream-builder). Id like the search bar to scroll up with the gridview. I've tried any number of ways to wrap the them in expanded/flexible widgets but I always end up with errors. Has anyone managed this?

Here's what i have right now, it will scroll but the search bar stays at the top.

```
new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Flexible(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0, right: 4.0),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.search),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                      child: Flexible(
                        child: new TextField(
                          onChanged: (String text) {
                            setState(() {
                              _searchController.text = text;
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Search...'),
                          controller: _searchController,
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new Flexible(
                child: new StreamBuilder(
                    stream: stgDocument.collection('people').orderBy('scroll').snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
                      _getMembers(snapshot);
                      return new GridView.builder(
                        //itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        itemCount: _searchedMemberList.length,
                        gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                            _buildPeopleCards(context, _searchedMemberList[index]),
                        //_buildPeopleCards(context, snapshot.data.documents[index])
                      );
                    }
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 17):

You can create a scrollable [ListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) with multiple children, one being a [GridView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html), with the structure below. To enable the scrolling for all of the elements in the `ListView`, you need to set its parameter `physics` to [NeverScrollablePhysics](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html).

```
 - ListView
   - Container // your searchbar would go here
   - GridView  // physics: NeverScrollablePhysics
     - Children
```

Here is a full code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 50.0,
            ),
            GridView.count(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: generateNumbers().map((int i) {
                return Text(i.toString());
              }).toList(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<int> generateNumbers() => List<int>.generate(30, (i) => i + 1);
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Animated Example]

Comment: @Alvindrakes always happy to help. Especially in the flutter community :)

Comment: Thanks alot. Been stuck on this forever.